How can I configure npm to correctly route?
NPM is not routing packages correctly with private registry setup
I'm stuck with a tricky npm configuration issue. We're using a private registry for our own packages and as a proxy for public npm packages, but npm keeps getting confused about where to look for things. Here's what's going on:
The Setup

We have a private registry (let's call it registry.example.com) that hosts our own packages and acts as a proxy for the public npm registry.
Our private packages are scoped like @mycompany/some-package.
Public packages should go through our proxy of the npm registry.

The Problem
When I try to install a package that has both private and public dependencies, npm gets mixed up. It's trying to find public packages (like lodash) in our private repo instead of the public npm proxy.
Here's an example error:
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.example.com/private-repo/lodash - not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'lodash@4.17.21' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

What I've Tried
I've been tweaking my .npmrc file to try and get the routing right. Here's my current setup:
registry=https://registry.example.com/npm-proxy/
@mycompany:registry=https://registry.example.com/private-repo/
//registry.example.com/:_password=<encrypted-password>
//registry.example.com/:username=exampleuser
//registry.example.com/:email=user@example.com
//registry.example.com/:always-auth=true
always-auth=true
strict-ssl=true

I thought this would make npm smart enough to look in the right places, but it's still getting confused.
The Tricky Part
Here's where it gets weird: when I'm working inside one of our private repos (like @mycompany/cool-project), I need npm to fetch other @mycompany packages from the private repo. But for any non-scoped packages, it should use the npm proxy.
I've tried setting up separate registries like this:
npm config set @mycompany:registry https://registry.example.com/private-repo/
npm config set registry https://registry.example.com/npm-proxy/

But it doesn't seem to solve the problem completely.
The Question
How can I configure npm to correctly route:

Scoped packages (@mycompany/*) to our private repo
All other packages to our proxy of the public npm registry

And have this work consistently, even when I'm inside a private package working on dependencies?
Any ideas would be super appreciated. I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I've been staring at this for hours and I'm out of ideas. Thanks in advance for any help!
